# JSONB Postgres map object to list of objects

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Let's say I have a following table in Postgres 14.

```
CREATE TABLE test(data jsonb);
```

Now I would insert the following JSON into the table.

```
INSERT INTO test 
values ('{"STATUS1": {"value1": "1", "value2":  "2"}, 
          "STATUS2": {"value1": "11", "value2": "22"}}');
```

The question that I have is, how could I transform this data using SQL and possibly Postgres JSONB functions in a query so the SELECT result would be a a following JSON array:

```json
[
  {"key": "STATUS1", "value1": "1", "value2": "2"}, 
  {"key": "STATUS2", "value1": "11", "value2": "22"}
]
```

Comment: `select jsonb_build_object('key', k)||v from test cross join lateral jsonb_each(data) as je(k,v);`

Comment: My mistake.  You want a json list, so wrap it in a `jsonb_agg()` like so:  `select jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('key', k)||v) from test cross join lateral jsonb_each(data) as je(k,v);`